# Torsion-free abelian groups $G,H$ such that $k[G] \cong k[H]$ (as rings) for any field $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups, group-rings

> Let $G,H$ be torsion-free abelian groups such that $k[G] \cong k[H]$ for any field $k$. Then is it true that $G \cong H$ ?

If this is not true, then what if I change the hypothesis to $R[G]\cong R[H]$ for any non-zero commutative unital ring; is the conclusion true then ?

Comment: I wonder what happens if one asks the same question but $k$ is fixed.

Comment: @Max : true , I wonder that too .

Comment: @Max : by Eric's answer , $k[G]^\times \cong k^\times \times G$ , so for a fixed $k$ , we atleast have $k^\times\times G \cong k^\times \times H$ ; where $k^\times , G,H$ are all abelian groups , so we can infer  that $G \cong H$ whenever $k^\times $ has the cancellation property in the category of abelian groups ; in particular when $k^\times$ is finitely generated , so at least when $k$ is finite

Comment: @Max : so in particular , having $k[G]^\times \cong k^\times \times G$ is a desirable property for our conclusion to hold ; and it is a conjecture of Kaplansky (the Units Conjecture) that whenever $k$ is a field and $G$ is torsion free , then  $k[G]^\times \cong k^\times \times G$

Comment: But this won't be enough : there is no cancellability property for arbitrary groups (although there is one for finite groups, but here $G$ is torsion free)

Comment: @Max : which comment are you referring to ? In my current set up , it IS enough as everything is abelian (http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1956-007-03/S0002-9939-1956-0078370-X/S0002-9939-1956-0078370-X.pdf ) . If we don't want the groups to be abelian , even then also, if $k$ is finite and Kaplansky's conjecture holds for any group $G$ over that field $k$ , then we can infer the affirmative result as $k^\times$ is finite ( we are cancelling $k^\times $ , not $G$  http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2317133.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A8f183354a8610501cec6b01165fcb67a )

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of the theorem you provided a link to, I thought finite groups could only be cancelled from finite groups. Then yes indeed, if Kaplansky's conjecture holds, it is true.

Comment: @Max : yes .. if $k$ is finite , and Kaplansky conjecture hold , and $G,H$ are torsion free then it is true ; if we assume $G,H$ to be abelian ; then $k^\times$ finitely generated is sufficient, and in general , if Kaplansky conjecture holds for the field $k$ , we assume $G,H$ to be torsion free and $k^\times$ has some suitable cancellation property ... these are sufficient conditions though ... there might be other ways of attack

Comment: (When you consider _finite_ abelian groups instead — which are torsion, of course — a related result is [Perlis-Walker theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Perlis-Walker_theorem)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group of units of $k[G]$ is exactly $k^\times\times G$.  In particular, if $k=\mathbb{F}_2$, then the group of units is $G$, so $G$ can be recovered from the ring $\mathbb{F}_2[G]$.

To prove this, note that any torsion-free abelian group $G$ admits a total ordering compatible with the group structure (choose a totally ordered basis for $G\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ and use the lexicographic order).  Considering $k[G]$ to be $G$-graded, suppose $u\in k[G]$ is a unit with inverse $v$.  Let $a$ be the minimum degree of a homogeneous part of $u$ and $b$ be the maximum degree, and let $c$ be the minimum degree of a homogeneous part of $v$ and $d$ be the maximum degree.  Then the product $uv$ has homogeneous parts of degree $a+c$ and also $b+d$.  Since $uv=1$, we must have $a+c=b+d$.  Since $a\leq b$ and $c\leq d$, this is only possible if $a=b$ and $c=d$, which means $u$ and $v$ are homogeneous.  That is, $u$ is a unit of $k$ times an element of $G$.

Comment: what is the grading that you give to $k[G]$ ?

Comment: A homogeneous element of degree $g$ is just anything of the form $ag$ for $a\in k$.

Comment: also I have made some comments following this question of mine , in reply to a comment of Max . Could you please enlighten more ? Thanks again

Comment: Related to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259117) : do you know what happens if we assume that $k(G) \cong k(H)$ for any field $k$? (Here $k(G)$ denotes the field of fractions of $k[G]$, whenever $G$ is a torsion-free abelian group).